# Localstorage and array

Tags: angular, typescript

```
  public arraySuccess = [];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.arraySuccess = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('success'));
  }
  openDialog(String) {
    this.dialog.open(RecommendationsDialog);

    if(this.arraySuccess != null && 
       this.arraySuccess.includes(String)) {
      return
    } else if (this.arraySuccess != null) {
      this.arraySuccess.push(String);
    }

    localStorage.setItem('success', JSON.stringify(this.arraySuccess));
    console.log(this.arraySuccess);

  }
```

There are articles (3 pcs). When opening, I would like to add their name to the `localstorage`. And if the user visits the page again, the read checkbox would be ticked. (checking if the given name is in the `localstorage` array)

But the problem is that I get `null` in the console.

Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: There is nothing writing to the console in the code. What error are you getting?

Comment: The parameter name `String` conflicts with the type name `String`; you may want to consider changing that to something more descriptive of the data being stored...

Comment: @Alejandro When i open popup with function ``openDialog``. And if i use ``console.log(this.arraySuccess)`` i got ``null`` everytime.

Comment: Perhaps you could add that `console.log` to the question's code? Currently it states "the problem is that I get `null` in the console", but there are no console statements in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Null value handling

Since localStorage.getItem() returns a value **or null**, you might want to ensure that arraySuccess is an array before calling the push method :

```
this.arraySuccess = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('success')) ?? [];
```

This way, even if it returns null, you'll save your element.

Also, declare your variable like so (instead of String) :

```
openDialog(myString: string) {
    this.dialog.open(RecommendationsDialog);
    if(this.arraySuccess.includes(myString)) {
      return
    } else {
      this.arraySuccess.push(myString);
    }
    localStorage.setItem('success', JSON.stringify(this.arraySuccess));
  }
```

Cheers

Edit: modified null handling thanks to Heretic Monkey

Comment: Angular uses TypeScript, where one does declare variable as seen in the OP if placed in a class. The code shown in the answer is the same as shown in the OP, so I'm not sure what the point is...

Comment: Could you elaborate ?

Comment: I was asking *you* to elaborate on your "Syntax alert!". There are no syntax errors in the OP's code.

Comment: No syntax error, but an argument called String which has type any is clearly a wrong practice in TS. You're right tho, the issue isn't syntax related.

Comment: Also, the code as written does not work; `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('success') || []);` will do `JSON.parse([])` which throws an error. It needs to be `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('success') || '[]');` or better yet `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('success')) ?? [];`